# Insertion Sort Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, insertion-sort

I have two global Variables `COUNT=0;` and `SIGN=0;`
Then I `#define SIZE 100`

I keep getting a seg fault in my code but I'm not too sure where, if you guys could help pin it down for me I'd appreciate it.

It is supposed to print out the total number of assignments that go on while it inserts data read in from a txt doc. I'm not sure if I am understanding what an assignment is actually but this is my go out of it.

```
void insert(int x[], int n){
int key,y,z;
COUNT++;
    for(z=1; z<n-1; z++){
        key=x[z];
        SIGN++;
        for(y=(z-1); y<0||key>=x[y]; y--){
            x[y+1]=x[y];
            SIGN++;
        }
        x[y+1]=KEY;
    }
int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("data.txt","r");
    int #temp;
    int i=0;
    int *sort=NULL;
    sort=(int *)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(sort));
    while(fp!=NULL){
        fscanf(fp, "%d", temp);
        sort[i]=(int)temp;
        i++;
    }
    insert(sort, SIZE);
    printf("number of Assignments=%d", SIGN);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't try this in a debugger, did you?

Comment: Probably not even to compile...

Comment: I try to run it in valgrind but it's saying I have bad permissions with fscanf and that I alloc twice but no frees

Comment: @Wingman Well.. That's the problem!

Comment: Your favorite debugger will tell you where the segfault occurs.

Answer (score 0):

In your below code,you not bother about the memory overflow.

```
while(fp!=NULL){
        fscanf(fp, "%d", temp);
        sort[i]=(int)temp;
        i++;
    }
```

Your allocated memory is SIZE*int*. If the file size is large(exceeds allocated memory size), then your code will access the memory beyond the allocated one. So this may cause the problem